# Ansible - ec2 tags replace as variables

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible

I'm trying to get the instance id of an ec2 base on its tags.

```
 - name: get instance_id of the last created ec2
    ec2_instance_facts:
      filters:
        "tag:Name": Example
    register: ec2_facts_result
```

on my filters i have there an example but it's hardcoded. i want to replace the "Name" and "Example" with variables. can some help me on this?

i have declared these variables

tag_name_1: "Env"
tag_value_1: "staging"

tried to run the filters using this syntax

```
- name: get instance_id of the last created ec2
  ec2_instance_facts:
  filters:
    "tag:{{ tag_name_1 }}": "{{ tag_value_1 }}"
  register: ec2_facts_result
```

but this is the result i've got.

```
"tag: {{ tag_name_1 }}": "staging"
```

It was able to capture the value of tag_value_1 but not the tag_name_1 variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a Jinja2 template rendering a dictionary as a value to the `filters` parameter, instead of specifying a dictionary in YAML:

```
filters: "{{ {'tag:' + tag_name_1: tag_value_1} }}"
```